What is the checksum algorithm for these messages?
I am attempting to reverse engineer a motor with an unknown CRC algorithm. I've used a logic analyzer to find these bytes, and I would like to send my own bytes back to the motor. Unfortunately, I can't find the CRC algorithm used to generate the 4 bytes at the end of the packet, and I'm wondering if some of the bytes are intentionally mixed up as part of the CRC process, or there is some form of encryption. Is there a chance I will be able to decode it?
           103 feee001500ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000b02833b2
           104 feee011500ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040500000000009384f2d2
           105 feee021500ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000af2d2dac
           106 feee001600070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000c477131f
           107 feee011600070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000e7dbd27f
           108 feee021600070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000db720d01
           109 feee001700070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000002815a31a
           110 feee011700070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000000bb9627a
           111 feee021700070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000003710bd04
           112 feee001800ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000343bc9aa
           113 feee011800ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000179708ca
           114 feee021800ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040000000000002b3ed7b4
           115 feee001900070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000401000000000098a1890c
           116 feee011900070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004010000000000bb0d486c
           117 feee021900070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000401000000000087a49712
           118 feee001a00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000ac065902
           119 feee011a00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040200000000008faa9862
           120 feee021a00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000b303471c
           121 feee001b00ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000009c19a4
           122 feee011b00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040300000000002330d8c4
           123 feee021b00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040300000000001f9907ba
           124 feee001c00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000c448f81f
           125 feee011c00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000e7e4397f
           126 feee021c00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000db4de601
           127 feee001d00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000282a481a
           128 feee011d00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040500000000000b86897a
           129 feee021d00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000372f5604
           130 feee001e00ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040600000000005c7568b7
           131 feee011e00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040600000000007fd9a9d7
           132 feee021e00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000437076a9
           133 feee001f00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000f0ef2811
           134 feee011f00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000d343e971
           135 feee021f00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000efea360f
           136 feee002000070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040000000000007c278a3b
           137 feee012000070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040000000000005f8b4b5b
           138 feee022000070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000400000000000063229425
           139 feee002100ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004010000000000d0bdca9d
           140 feee012100ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004010000000000f3110bfd
           141 feee022100ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004010000000000cfb8d483
           142 feee002200070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000a4e2ea30
           143 feee012200070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000874e2b50
           144 feee022200070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000bbe7f42e
           145 feee002300070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000403000000000048805a35
           146 feee012300070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040300000000006b2c9b55
           147 feee022300070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040300000000005785442b
           148 feee002400ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000008c54bb8e
           149 feee012400ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000aff87aee
           150 feee022400ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000009351a590
           151 feee002500070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000405000000000020cefb28
           152 feee012500070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000405000000000003623a48
           153 feee022500070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040500000000003fcbe536
           154 feee002600070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000406000000000014692b26
           155 feee012600070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000406000000000037c5ea46
           156 feee022600070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040600000000000b6c3538
           157 feee002700ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000b8f36b80
           158 feee012700ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000009b5faae0
           159 feee022700ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000a7f6759e
           160 feee002800070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000a4dd0130
           161 feee012800070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040000000000008771c050
           162 feee022800070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000bbd81f2e
           163 feee002900070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000401000000000048bfb135
           164 feee012900070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040100000000006b137055
           165 feee022900070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000401000000000057baaf2b
           166 feee002a00ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040200000000003ce09198
           167 feee012a00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040200000000001f4c50f8
           168 feee022a00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000402000000000023e58f86
           169 feee002b00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000907ad13e
           170 feee012b00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000b3d6105e
           171 feee022b00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040300000000008f7fcf20
           172 feee002c00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000001456c026
           173 feee012c00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000404000000000037fa0146
           174 feee022c00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000000b53de38
           175 feee002d00ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000b8cc8080
           176 feee012d00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040500000000009b6041e0
           177 feee022d00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000a7c99e9e
           178 feee002e00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000cc93a02d
           179 feee012e00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000ef3f614d
           180 feee022e00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000d396be33
           181 feee002f00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000407000000000020f11028
           182 feee012f00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000035dd148
           183 feee022f00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000003ff40e36
           184 feee003000ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040000000000008c2a6d8f
           185 feee013000ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000af86acef
           186 feee023000ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000932f7391
           187 feee003100070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000401000000000020b02d29
           188 feee013100070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004010000000000031cec49
           189 feee023100070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040100000000003fb53337
           190 feee003200070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040200000000001417fd27
           191 feee013200070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000402000000000037bb3c47
           192 feee023200070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040200000000000b12e339
           193 feee003300ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000b88dbd81
           194 feee013300ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040300000000009b217ce1
           195 feee023300ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000a788a39f
           196 feee003400070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000007c595c3a
           197 feee013400070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000005ff59d5a
           198 feee023400070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000635c4224
           199 feee003500070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000903bec3f
           200 feee013500070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000b3972d5f
           201 feee023500070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040500000000008f3ef221
           202 feee003600ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000e464cc92
           203 feee013600ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000c7c80df2
           204 feee023600ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000fb61d28c
           205 feee003700070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000407000000000048fe8c34
           206 feee013700070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000006b524d54
           207 feee023700070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000407000000000057fb922a
           208 feee003800070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000400000000000014281627
           209 feee013800070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040000000000003784d747
           210 feee023800070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040000000000000b2d0839
           211 feee003900ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004010000000000b8b25681
           212 feee013900ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040100000000009b1e97e1
           213 feee023900ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004010000000000a7b7489f
           214 feee003a00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000cced762c
           215 feee013a00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000ef41b74c
           216 feee023a00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000d3e86832
           217 feee003b00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000208fc629
           218 feee013b00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000403000000000003230749
           219 feee023b00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040300000000003f8ad837
           220 feee003c00ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000e45b2792
           221 feee013c00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000c7f7e6f2
           222 feee023c00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004040000000000fb5e398c
           223 feee003d00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000405000000000048c16734
           224 feee013d00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040500000000006b6da654
           225 feee023d00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000405000000000057c4792a
           226 feee003e00070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040600000000007c66b73a
           227 feee013e00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040600000000005fca765a
           228 feee023e00070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040600000000006363a924
           229 feee003f00ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000d0fcf79c
           230 feee013f00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000f35036fc
           231 feee023f00ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004070000000000cff9e982
           232 feee004000070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000dc1afa49
           233 feee014000070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000ffb63b29
           234 feee024000070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004000000000000c31fe457
           235 feee004100070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000401000000000030784a4c
           236 feee014100070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000401000000000013d48b2c
           237 feee024100070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040100000000002f7d5452
           238 feee004200ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f1400000402000000000044276ae1
           239 feee014200ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004020000000000678bab81
           240 feee024200ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040200000000005b2274ff
           241 feee004300070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000e8bd2a47
           242 feee014300070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000cb11eb27
           243 feee024300070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004030000000000f7b83459
           244 feee004400070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000006c913b5f
           245 feee014400070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040400000000004f3dfa3f
           246 feee024400070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000404000000000073942541
           247 feee004500ffff00000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000c00b7bf9
           248 feee014500ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000e3a7ba99
           249 feee024500ffff00000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004050000000000df0e65e7
           250 feee004600070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000b4545b54
           251 feee014600070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f1400000406000000000097f89a34
           252 feee024600070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f14000004060000000000ab51454a
           253 feee004700070700000020421000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000005836eb51
           254 feee014700070700000020420000ff7f805ce97f140000040700000000007b9a2a31

Further packets I recorded today (I can play the packets on the bus as much as I want and the motor will respond):
packets = [
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000002300ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000ced7fe0f'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000002100ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000736677da'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001f00ff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000007714d424'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001d00ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000caa55df1'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001b00ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000ba6a068b'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001900ff7ffd6a00800000e42702000000000007db8f5e'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001700ff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000005af4b17f'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001500ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000e74538aa'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001300ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000978a63d0'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000001100ff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000002a3bea05'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000f00ff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000002dd41f92'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000d00ff7ffd6a00800000e42702000000000090659647'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000b00ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000e0aacd3d'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000900ff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000005d1b44e8'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000700ff7ffd6a00800000e42702000000000000347ac9'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000500ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000bd85f31c'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000300ff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000cd4aa866'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000100ff7ffd6a00800000e42702000000000070fb21b3'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff0000000000000000ff7ffd6a00800000e42702000000000075ad855b'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000feffff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000309d075c'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000fcffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000008d2c8e89'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000faffff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000fde3d5f3'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000f8ffff7ffd6a00800000e42702000000000040525c26'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000f6ffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000001d7d6207'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000f4ffff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000a0ccebd2'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000f2ffff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000d003b0a8'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000f0ffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000006db2397d'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000eeffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000006a5dccea'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000ecffff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000d7ec453f'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000eaffff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000a7231e45'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000e8ffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000001a929790'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000e5ffff7ffd6a00800000e427020000000000ff5a848c'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000e3ffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000008f95dff6'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000e1ffff7ffd6a00800000e42702000000000032245623'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000dfffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000003656f5dd'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba0aff000000000000ddffff7ffd6a00800000e4270200000000008be77c08'),
    ]
    
    exit_packets = [
        bytes.fromhex('feee00ba00ff00000000000000000000805ce97f000000000200000000000d209555'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee01ba00ff00000000000000000000805ce97f00000000020000000000744c9f83'),
        bytes.fromhex('feee02ba00ff00000000000000000000805ce97f0000000002000000000048e540fd')
    ]


Additional data of different length (These include the reply packet):
feee020100002400c6202c41000055004d74373b0000000000002a000000082f000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000062bf06000000b514b033
feee008c00ff00000000000000000000805ce97f00000000040000000000b5700c71
feee000100002500c93d2a41ffff36007d24b93b000000000000f1ff00003c24000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000000006210070000009c034579
feee018c00ff00000000000000000000805ce97f00000000040000000000cc1c06a7
feee010100001d00b4282b4100008aff0f5bd0ba000000000000020000008218000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000062f60600000020f544f9
feee028c00ff00000000000000000000805ce97f00000000040000000000f0b5d9d9
feee020100002400c6202c410200f5ffa8d9e73a000000000000e9ff0000072f000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000062bf060000009e472426


Welcome to SE/RE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Please [edit] your question to a more meaningful title, as we cannot know whether you have hope or not. Then add the CRC parameter sets (according to chapter 16 of http://ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) you have already checked and rejected.

@jsotola thanks

@thebusybee I've checked them all with reveng, I believe it to be encrypted or perhaps the packet order is intentionally mixed up.

Please [edit] your question to add such information, this is not a forum. Since the number of CRC parameter sets is finite, please list the ones you mean by "checked them all."-- Also add the known details of the message, header, data, fields, whatever you know. If this has some external documentation, add the relevant parts (questions need to be self-contained) and the link to the source.

Which engine controller is it exactly? Do you have the firmware image from the module?
